# Pure CSS mobile toggle menu using :focus has issue with non-menu links failing

Tags: css, mobile, menu, hyperlink, focus

I'm trying to create simple mobile version of my simple horizontal one-level top menu. I'd like to replace the horizontal top nav with a vertical menu that is initially hidden but shows up when the user clicks the simple menu link in the top right of the screen.

In fact you can see what I've built so far at http://www.janparker.co.uk if you squeeze you window to be less than 768px.

It's almost a beautifully simply pure CSS result.

The menu works perfectly, but if a user first clicks on "menu" to activate the menu, then doesn't use the menu but instead clicks on some other link on the page OUTSIDE of the menu, a problem arises.

The link outside the doesn't work. Worse because the menu also closes and the page scrolls (both natural and not undesirable behaviors) the combination is utterly disorienting to the user if they are scrolled a long way down the page.

The code is:

`<a id="menu-invoker" tabindex="0">Menu</a>
<nav><ul><li>First menu item</li><li>second menu item</li></ul></nav>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Some other link</a></p>`

`#menu-invoker:focus ~ nav {display: block;}
nav {display:none;}
ul:focus, ul:active, ul:hover {display: block;}`

or see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YNxVs/1/

Any solutions? What's the simplest way to achieve this?
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `#menu-invoker` no longer has `:focus`. One solution might be to `position: absolute;` the nav, so it floats on top of the other content. That way the scroll-height will never change.

(the links outside the menu work in Firefox, but not in IE or Webkit. Not sure which is doing it "wrong")